# match text inside quotes inside curly brackets

Tags: regex

I have following text

```
{"inside1", "inside2"}, "bla", "bla"
```

and I want to extract only text inside double quotes and inside curly brackets, so result in this case should be "inside1" and "inside2".

I am trying with `{"(.*?)"}` with global flag but it doesn't work :(.

Comment: Where are you getting the data from? Which language are you using?

Comment: Unless you are able to use lookbehinds with quantifiers (which in most cases, you aren't), I don't think this is easily solvable with just one regex. I recommend that you split this up into two regexes, first get all the stuff between curly braces with one regex, then capture the stuff inside the quotations with another.

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that this is a valid Python tuple literal, made up of Python set and string literals? If not, then (a) you probably shouldn't be creating the data this way, but (b) if you have no choice in the interchange format and it really is just Python literals, use `literal_eval` to parse it.

Comment: At any rate, this doesn't appear to be a regular language, meaning you shouldn't be trying to parse it with regular expressions. It does look like a very simple language to parse one level up; any parser generator or parser library should be able to handle it easily. But without knowing what language you want to do this in, or what libraries you're familiar with, it's hard to give anything more specific.

Comment: The OP doesn't comment so I don't think it deserves further help. Voting close based on "__unclear what you're asking__"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use with only one regex. However, you can use two regexes to do this.

First regex you can use, is to extract the content within `{` and `}`, so you can use:

```
{(.*)}
```

Then, if you have the string:

```
{"inside1", "inside2", noquote}, "bla"
```

This will capture: `"inside1", "inside2", noquote`

**[1st regex working demo](https://regex101.com/r/cJ6oF8/1)**

Once you capture this content, you can use this second regex over the previous result like this:

```
"(.*?)"
```

This will capture: `inside1` and `inside2`

**[2nd regex working demo](https://regex101.com/r/cJ6oF8/2)**

Answer (score 0):

with the new [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) you can use that with findall:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|{)[^"}]*"([^"]*)"
```

where `\G` is the position after the last match.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/fY2eG0/1)